# Counter intuitive composite function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions

I was asked to give an example of two functions where $f(x)\rightarrow b$ as $x\rightarrow a$ and $g(y)\rightarrow c$ as $y\rightarrow b$, but $g(f(x))\nrightarrow c$ as $x\rightarrow a$. At first I thought this would be an easy problem, but then I started to realise that I couldn't come up with a single example. In what sense do I have to look at this problem to solve it? I tried constructing $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ with functions such as $e^x$, $1/x$, $\sin x$, $\ln x$, but none of them seemed to work. I considered messing around with the domains of functions, but then I realised that $x\rightarrow a$, for example, does not say whether $x$ is approached from the right side, or the left side of the real numbers. If anyone could clarify this problem a bit for me, that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can achieve what we want by making $f(x)$ just be the constant function $b$ and make $g(y)$ have a jump discontinuity at $y=b$ (say $g(y) = c$ for $y \neq b$ and $g(b) = c+1$). Then $g(f(x)) = g(b) = c+1$ for all $x$, whence $\lim\limits_{x\to a}g(f(x)) = c+1 \neq c$, and the other requirements are also fulfilled.

The key to this solution is that the value of a function **at** a point does not affect its limit as we approach that. We chose to make $f(x)$ constant so that $g(f(x))$ was constant, and we defined $g(y)$ in such a way that we have a jump discontinuity at $y=b$ (the constant value of $f$), but $g(y)$ still has limit $c$ as $y\to b$ because everywhere around $b$, we made $g(y)=c$.

Comment: You are right, that is indeed very simple, and I feel like I should have been able to think of it myself. Guess I tried to complicate it too much. Thank you very much.